# VBA - Load event code not running

Tags: vba, userform

I have a very simple form that, when loaded, should create a new object `Thing` that is defined in a specific Class Module. The UF also has several buttons associated to different functions.

This is the UF's code associate to the load event:

```
Option Explicit
Private mth As Thing

Private Sub UserForm_Load()
   Set mth = New Thing
   mth.Name = InputBox("Enter a name for the Thing")
End Sub
```

If I F5 directly on this, the UF shows up but the code doesn't run furth and the `Thing` object `mth` is not even created ...

I also tried to call the form from a module with the following code but the result was the same:

```
Sub test()

 Dim uf As Object
 Set uf = New Dinamico 'this is the name of the UserForm
 Load uf

End Sub
```

As result, I would like that each time that the form is loaded, a new `mth` was created and an InputBox asking for the name appeared. I have the feeling to be missing something very stupid...could you help me out please ?

Comment: In VBA, double click on the form (not on the buttons, but on the form) and write the code in the automatic macro, appearing there.

Comment: Try `UserForm_Activate()` instead of `UserForm_Load()`

Comment: what is `Private Sub UserForm_Load()` ? I know `Private Sub UserForm_Activate()` or `Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()` to load a User_Form in VBA

Comment: @gizlmo Yeah I already tried with activate and it works, but I wanted to understand why it doesn't with Load...

Comment: @ShaiRadio https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/138819

Comment: @Vityata in that way I would associate the `mth` creation to UserForm_Click. What I want, instead, is to create it everytime that the UF is loaded (not activate, loaded)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your code within

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

End Sub
```

UserForm_Load is in VB.Net while in VBA its UserForm_Initialize.